# I want to rewrite the url in corephp using .htaccess

Tags: php

http://localhost/rankeyiansacademy/course_details?id=digital-marketing-training

to

http://localhost/rankeyiansacademy/courses/digital-marketing-training

How can I change the url using htaccess in corephp?

Comment: What is the question? Also, what have you tried and it's not working as you expect?

Comment: You can use http://www.visiospark.com/mod-rewrite-rule-generator/ for generation of the rewrite condition for your htaccess file

Comment: @Alex Andrei My httaccess code is - # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteEngine On    
# enable symbolic links

Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +MultiViews
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^courses/(\d+)*$ ./course_details.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ course_details?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

Comment: please edit your question to include your `.htaccess` code, it's quite difficult to read it from the comment

Comment: Modified declaration of desire into question

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping on your wamp/xampp rewrite module is on as required. 
Then define `$base_url = http://localhost/rankeyiansacademy` in your config file or `<base href="http://localhost/rankeyiansacademy/">` tag in html. 
In your .htaccess file, add following code

```
RewriteRule ^courses/([A-Za-z-]+)$ course_details.php?id=$1
```

Then change the links in html like 
If you define base tag, then use the following changes in html

```
<a href = "courses/digital-marketing-training">Link</a>
```

If you define variable in your config file,

```
 <a href = "<?php echo $base_url; ?>/courses/digital-marketing-training">Link</a>
```

This one works for me. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for url rewrite, then you can use the Apache mod_rewrite module.

Apart from core php, if we use cms frameworks like wordpress, drupal, cakePHP, Zend, expression engine frameworks will implement url rewriting very easily.

Search engines like clean URLs pretty much and you should consider implementing it.

You can use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can help you:

Write below code in your .htaccess file.

**For detail page write:** RewriteRule ^courses/([^/]+) course_details.php?id=$1 [NC]

**For all course page:** RewriteRule ^courses courses.php [NC]

Hope this can help you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can Use URL rewrite in htaccess File.

Put .htaccess file in main folder and use below code.It will read like if your URL http://example.com/index.php?page=search it will show like this http://example.com/search. This may help you to find solution

Code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /product\.php\?cat=(search)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^(search)$ /product.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```